# Printing an Array as a table in Ruby

Tags: ruby

My current code is...

```
print_line
processes = @client.sys.process.get_processes
blacklist = ["NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM", "NT AUTHORITY\\LOCAL SERVICE", "NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORK SERVICE"]
filtered = processes.map!{|i| i.slice!("arch", "session", "path")}.reject {|h| blacklist.include? h['user']}
filtered.each do |r|
puts r.map { |p| p}.join(" ")
end
```

Here is the output...

```
pid 0 ppid 0 name [System Process] user 
pid 456 ppid 320 name explorer.exe user CLINE\Administrator
pid 544 ppid 204 name TPAutoConnect.exe user CLINE\Administrator
pid 1096 ppid 456 name vmtoolsd.exe user CLINE\Administrator
pid 180 ppid 456 name rundll32.exe user CLINE\Administrator
pid 1208 ppid 724 name logon.scr user CLINE\Administrator
```

here is the array...

```
[*] [{"pid"=>0, "ppid"=>0, "name"=>"[System Process]", "user"=>""}, {"pid"=>456,       "ppid"=>320, "name"=>"explorer.exe", "user"=>"CLINE\\Administrator"}, {"pid"=>544, "ppid"=>204, "name"=>"TPAutoConnect.exe", "user"=>"CLINE\\Administrator"}, {"pid"=>1096, "ppid"=>456, "name"=>"vmtoolsd.exe", "user"=>"CLINE\\Administrator"}, {"pid"=>180, "ppid"=>456, "name"=>"rundll32.exe", "user"=>"CLINE\\Administrator"}, {"pid"=>1208, "ppid"=>724, "name"=>"logon.scr", "user"=>"CLINE\\Administrator"}]
```

But I want the output to be like a table, like this

```
pid         ppid        name    user

1           0         x.exe     me

2           1         y.exe    you
```

What am I missing in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` to print fixed width columns. First get whatever the max length for each column is then use sprintf and join with `"\t"` all values:

```
max_length = filtered.inject({}) {|m,e| e.each{|key,value| m[key] = [key.length, m[key].to_i, value.to_s.length].max}; m}
puts filtered.collect{|e| e.collect{|key,value| sprintf("%#{max_length[key]}s", value)}.join("\t")}
```

*update:* To print out the header, the following can be used

Left Aligned:

```
max_length.collect{|key, value| sprintf("%-#{value}s", key)}.join("\t")
```

Right Aligned:

```
max_length.collect{|key, value| sprintf("%#{value}s", key)}.join("\t")
```

Comment: Can the Key be added to the top of each column?